# Raspbian/Linux how can I run my R scripts as crontabs?

Tags: r, cron, raspbian

This is probably a very basic question but I'm new to this:
I'm trying to schedule some Rscript on my Raspberry Pi but keep failing with it. First it didn't do anything and now it says that it can't run my crontabs because they have 'bad commands'.

I have tried in two different styles:

```
sudo crontab -e

17**** cd [/home/pi/R/projects] && Rscript scraper_srf.R
20**** cd [/home/pi/R/projects] && Rscript scraper_srf.R
29**** cd [/home/pi/R/projects] && Rscript 20min_retry_update_08_06_2020.R
30 21*** cd [/home/pi/R/projects] && Rscript soweitsieht_update_10_06_2020.R
```

and

```
sudo crontab -e

32**** Rscript /home/pi/R/projects/scraper_srf.R
20**** Rscript /home/pi/R/projects/scraper_blick.R
29**** Rscript /home/pi/R/projects/20min_retry_update_08_06_2020.R
3021*** Rscript /home/pi/R/projects/soweitsieht_update_10_06_2020.R
```

thx for your help

Comment: `32 * * * * Rscript /home/pi/R/projects/scraper_srf.R`? Not tried but feel like there has to be a space between *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach worked for me :

1) make a shell script (myScript.sh) along with your R files

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /myScriptDir
Rscript myScript.R
```

2) test the shell script

```
cd /myScriptDir
sh myScript.sh
```

3) edit crontab :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 8 * * * sh /myScriptDir/myScript.sh
```

as mentionned by @amatsuo_net, space between * is necessary

Comment: man, getting into linux is not easy. but now it works so thx a lot!