# How to always run reactiveTimer in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app hosted on ec2/ubuntu

In the config I have `app_idle_timeout 0;`

I have a `reactiveTimer` with `session = NULL` that needs to run the same piece of code every 30 minutes.

It works perfectly when I have my app opened in my browser window but doesn't run whenever the app window is closed.

Is there any way to force the app to run 24/7 and thus execute the script every 30 min?

Comment: as your app is hosted on a linux system, you could use `crontab` [to run a R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319407/raspbian-linux-how-can-i-run-my-r-scripts-as-crontabs/62320335?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.7810#62320335), and then read the result periodically from the app when it's open.

Comment: Not an option, the script needs to run a shiny funciton `  shiny:::handlerManager$addHandler`