# How to schedule data refresh in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've dashboard built using R Shiny. I use global.R, ui.R and server.R files. I've found this link [How to trigger a data refresh in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680246/how-to-trigger-a-data-refresh-in-shiny) that suggests using `invalidateLater`. But I use my global.R file to get the data from a cloud MySQL database, perform necessary data wrangling in the same global.R file. Could someone please let me know how to schedule a daily data refresh.

Comment: The data update needs to be done using reactives in `server.R`. You could use [reactivePoll](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html) for this

Comment: @Waldi, so there'd be no use of global.R ? I have multiple plots and data tables, for each plot, I need to get the data once then?

Comment: `global.R`is for static configuration data. `reactives` in `server.R` will allow to update data dynamically.

Comment: @Waldi, could you please tell if there's a difference between invalidateLater and reactivePoll?

Comment: The principle is similar, see [15.4.1 Polling](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-objects.html)

Comment: @Waldi, I asked another question regarding date-time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286092/r-shiny-daterange-shows-non-existent-date-in-data. Could you please have a look

Comment: @Waldi, after running the App, the datetimes as in UTC, after deployment it's again back to IST (my time). But the issue of having an extra date even though that date is not there in the date still persists.

Comment: You could perhaps have a look at `lubridate::with_tz`and `lubridate::force_tz` to manage timezone as you wish

Comment: @Waldi, one query, I just read that in order to use reactivePoll, the dashboard can't be idle. I just need to refresh data only twice a day. Will cronjob be a better option in that case?

Comment: cronjob is an useful option for a twice a day refresh. You could schedule an Rscript to update a data file (.rds for example) and read this data file in `server.R`. This is actually what I usually do.

Comment: @Waldi, can't thank enough for the help Waldi. Will look up the solution you use.

Comment: The following link might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319407/raspbian-linux-how-can-i-run-my-r-scripts-as-crontabs/62320335#62320335

Comment: Hi I still struggle with the difference of updating plots in the global file each day or in the server side. The way I work is that I run daily a data wrangling script which gives output of plots as .RData files. These are saved to Google Drive. Once this is finished I want to refresh them in my Shiny app. I do it like this cause it takes ome time to generate these plots via various functions...and to read in .RData files it goes much quicker