# R Shiny daterange shows non existent date in data

Tags: r, shiny

I have a histogram plot that has `dateRangeInput`. the code for the `menuItem` is:

```
            menuItem(text = 'Plot', tabName = 'Plots', icon = icon('chart-bar')),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.menu == 'Plots'",
                             dateRangeInput('daterange', 'Enter Start and End Date', start = min(wide_data$SampleTime), end = max(wide_data$SampleTime), min = min(wide_data$SampleTime), max = max(wide_data$SampleTime)),
                             selectInput('UserSelect', 'Select a Vehicle', choices = c('All',unique(wide_data$device_user))),
                             selectInput('variableselect', 'Select a Variable', choices = names(wide_data)[-c(1,2)]),
                             sliderInput('binscount', 'Observations', min = 10, value = 30, max = 50)
            ),
```

If we check the max `SampleTime`:

```
max(wide_data$SampleTime)
[1] "2020-12-13"
```

[image]

The original SampleTime is actually in POSIXct format but in Indian Standard Time (IST), I use this code to keep in IST time zone:

```
mutate(SampleTime = as.Date(SampleTime, tz = 'Asia/Kolkata'))
```

Could someone please let me know why I am seeing 2020-12-14 when the maximum available date in the data is 2020-12-13?

sample data:

```
dput(tail(wide_data,300))
structure(list(SampleTime = structure(c(18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18608, 18608, 18608, 18608, 18608, 18605, 
18605, 18605, 18605, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 
18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18606, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 
18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18607, 18608, 18608, 18608
), class = "Date"), device_user = c("Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", "Not deployed", 
"Not deployed", "Not deployed"), `ENGINE RPM` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `VEHICLE SPEED` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `ACCELERATION X` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `ACCELERATION Y` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `ACCELERATION Z` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `EXTERNAL BATTERY` = c(11.4, 
11, 12.2, 12.6, 11.2, 11, 12.4, 12.6, 11.2, 12.4, 12.6, 11.2, 
12.4, 12.6, 11.6, 11.2, 12.4, 12.6, 11.2, 12.2, 12.4, 11.4, 11, 
10.8, 12.4, 12.6, 11, 12.4, 11.4, 11, 12.2, 12.4, 11.4, 11, 12.4, 
11.2, 12.2, 12.4, 11.4, 11.2, 12.6, 12.4, 12.6, 11.4, 12.4, 11.6, 
11, 12.4, 12.6, 11, 12.4, 12.6, 11, 10.6, 12.2, 12.6, 11.2, 12.4, 
12.6, 11.2, 12.6, 11, 12.6, 11.4, 12.6, 12.4, 11.4, 11, 12.4, 
11.2, 11, 12.4, 11.2, 11, 12.4, 11.4, 12.4, 11.2, 11, 12.4, 12.6, 
11, 12.4, 12.6, 11, 12.2, 12.6, 12.2, 12.6, 12.4, 11.6, 11, 12.4, 
11.4, 12.6, 12.4, 12.2, 12.4, 11.2, 11.2, 11, 11, 10.8, 10.6, 
11.2, 11, 11, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.8, 11, 11, 11, 10.6, 10.6, 
10.6, 10.6, 10.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), IGNTIONSTATUS = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

Comment: Can you provide example data? Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: @starja, have added some data, thing is it's a pivot_wider data with good amount of NAs, total row count is more than 300K. Please let me know if you are unable to recreate the issue. Have chosen tail because data is until Dec 13, but in my dashboard as you can see, it's till 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `wide_data$SampleTime` is `UTC`:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct('2020-12-13 22:30',tz = 'UTC'),tz='Asia/Kolkata')
[1] "2020-12-14"
```

to verify this, run:

```
lubridate::tz(wide_data$SampleTime)
```

If above function either result in "UTC" or "", solution is then:

```
mutate(SampleTime = as.Date(SampleTime, tz = 'UTC'))
```

Comment: Thanks Waldi, but I need the dates to be in IST or 'Asia/Kolkata', then can I use mutate(SampleTime = as.Date(SampleTime, tz = ''Asia/Kolkata''))

Comment: datetimes after conversion to date don't have time zones because they  have lost time information

Comment: wide_data$SampleTime is indeed in UTC, not sure how it changed. The original pre-wide data has datetime and I use this code to convert it to just date: mutate(SampleTime = as.Date(SampleTime, tz = 'Asia/Kolkata')). Not sure why it again automatically gets converted to UTC

Comment: my impression is that the original data is `UTC` which would explain the `12-14`

Comment: It's not, I double checked with the raw data in MySQL. Is there anyway we can make the just SampleTime date column in wide_data back to 'Asia/Kolkata' tz?

Comment: as explained in my comments above, date doesn't have anymore timezone. see the `dput` you provided.

Comment: OK, will loop up what I can do, thanks for your help.

Comment: Another possibility is that `wide_data$SampleTime` has not timezone, in which case `as.Date` will consider it as UTC. if `lubridate::tz(wide_data$SampleTime)==''` this is what will happen

Comment: actually it's the pre-wide data that doesnt have a timezone. wide_data is UTC. Can you please suggest a workaround.

Comment: if pre-wide_data has no timezone, then `mutate(SampleTime = as.Date(SampleTime, tz = 'UTC'))` as suggested in my answer should work.